# ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework ‘Alamofire’

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to run tests on this project on xcode and seem to have issues with the build and can run the tests. the warning are below:

In FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS on Build settings, I can't find all pods installed in the search paths, not like in the Debug schema. In test schema, there is only the pods below:

```
//:configuration = Debug
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Nimble" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/Quick" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/RxAtomic" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/RxBlocking" "${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/RxSwift"
```

The warning:

```
: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework ‘RxCocoa’
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework ‘SnapKit’
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework ‘Alamofire’
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework ‘Hero’
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework ‘KingfisherWebP’
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework ‘QuickLayout’
```

my podfile :

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

#plugin 'cocoapods-binary'

use_modular_headers!
use_frameworks!
#all_binary!
inhibit_all_warnings!
enable_bitcode_for_prebuilt_frameworks! 


abstract_target 'buyer' do
  # Pods for buyer

# Networking
  pod 'Moya/RxSwift', '14.0.0'
  
  # Rx Extensions
  pod 'RxDataSources', '~> 4.0'  # https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources
  pod 'RxSwiftExt', '~> 5.0'  # https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt
  pod 'NSObject+Rx', '~> 5.0'  # https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/NSObject-Rx
  pod 'RxViewController', '~> 1'  # https://github.com/devxoul/RxViewController 
   # rest of the pods

  target 'app1'
  target 'app2'
  
  target 'buyerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'Quick', '~> 3.1.2'  # https://github.com/Quick/Quick
    pod 'Nimble', '~> 9.0.0'  # https://github.com/Quick/Nimble
    #pod 'RxNimble'#, '4.7.2'  # https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxNimble
    pod 'RxAtomic', :modular_headers => true
    pod 'RxBlocking'  # https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift
  end
end

target 'buyerUITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
end

deployment_target = '12.0'


post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = deployment_target
      end
    end
    project.build_configurations.each do |bc|
      bc.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = deployment_target
    end
  end
  
  Dir.glob(installer.sandbox.target_support_files_root + "Pods-*/*.sh").each do |script|
    flag_name = File.basename(script, ".sh") + "-Installation-Flag"
    folder = "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"
    file = File.join(folder, flag_name)
    content = File.read(script)
    content.gsub!(/set -e/, "set -e\nKG_FILE=\"#{file}\"\nif [ -f \"$KG_FILE\" ]; then exit 0; fi\nmkdir -p \"#{folder}\"\ntouch \"$KG_FILE\"")
    File.write(script, content)
  end
end
```